# How to load balance two urls with nginx?

Tags: server, nginx, webapps

I have a python(flask) webapp. It is accessible by nginx in front of it.

Let, my domain is: http://domain.com

My web app is running on http://127.0.0.1:5000

nginx config:

```
upstream fapp {
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location {                                                         
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;                     
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;                   
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
          proxy_pass http://fapp/;                               
          proxy_intercept_errors on;                                   
    }
}
```

This app has two functionality or route:

1. http://127.0.0.1/dataone/1
2. http://127.0.0.1/datatwo/1

Let, first one will give a page with some graphical details of data id 1 and second one will give the details without any graphical view.

What I want is a way if I hit http://domain.com/data/1 , nginx will give me data from either "http://127.0.0.1/dataone/1" or "http://127.0.0.1/datatwo/1".

How can I do that?

UPDATE 1:
From the clue of @Oldskool, I did look at split clients module.

```
    upstream fapp {
            server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    }


split_clients "${remote_addr}" $mydata {
        50%     "dataone";
        50%     "datatwo";
        *       "";
}


    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        location {                                                         
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;                     
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;                   
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
              proxy_pass http://fapp/;                               
              proxy_intercept_errors on;                                   
        }


location /data/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://fapp/${mydata}/;
                proxy_intercept_errors on;
}
}
```

But problem is if i access  http://domain.com/data/1 or  http://domain.com/data/35 or anything on that number is not working, it redirects to the url http://fapp/dataone/1 or 35. Is there anymore things to add or I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Looks like you want to use the split_clients module: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know  this module. Let me update the question now.

Comment: @Oldskool , please have a look at the update. Thanks in advance. :)